# Analysis of chess by Philidor in PGN

Tags: books, pgn

Where can I find games annotated by Philidor in his book in    a PGN file?

Answer (score 1):

You can find Philidor’s 1790 book [here](https://books.google.com/books/about/Analysis_of_the_Game_of_Chess.html?id=d2jnqeVdIdQC) in a free Google Books scanned eBook of it.

Comment: Link works now.  revoted.  Do not see a pgn file though but that is a different issue.

Comment: Maybe.  I thought he wanted to read the games online in PGN but the games were from the book by Philidor. If he did want PDF you answered it.